# Export SQL table into a fixed length format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, concatenation

I currently have data in my tables that are formatted like:

```
County     Office     First Name     Last Name
01         01         John           Smith
99         01         Jane           Cole
```

I need to export it into a fixed length text file using SQL. Output should look like this:

```
0101JohnSmith
9901JaneCole
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What database platform, please?

Comment: Do you want *fixed length* or no spaces? There is a big difference.

Comment: The database is SQL Sever 2008, and I would like to write it to a fixed length file.  eg. characters 1-2= county code, 3-4 office, 5-25= First Name, 25-45=Last Name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming all columns are `NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT [County]         -- already matches length of 2?
     + [Office]         -- ... ditto
     + right('                    ' + [First Name], 20)
     + right('                    ' + [Last Name], 20)
FROM   tbl
```

Yes, that is a string of 20 blanks up there. So `[First Name]` and `[Last Name]` name will be blank-padded to the *left* and *always* be 20 characters long.

Or, if you want the string to be padded to the *right*:

```
left([First Name] + '                    ', 20)
```

Comment: I see what your doing.  I guess now I'm wondering how I would write that out to a .txt file?  Is that possible in SQL '08?

Comment: @evglynn: There is quite a few [answers here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server-2008]+export+text+file) for that.